# How to fix "wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plot

I am trying to make 6 separate graphs from a dataframe that has 5 columns and multiple rows that is imported from Excel. I want to add two lines to the graph that are the point in the dataframe plus and minus the rolling standard deviation at each point in each column and row of the dataframe. To do this I am using a nested for loop and then graphing, however, it is saying wrong number of items pass placement implies 1. I do not know how to fix this.

I have tried converting the dataframe to a list and appending rows as well. Nothing seems to work. I know this could be easily done.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
excel_file = 'C:/Users/afrydman/Documents/Storage and Data Centers FFO Multiples Data.xlsx'
dfStorage = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name='Storage Data', index_col='Date')
dfrollingStd = dfStorage.rolling(12).std().shift(-11)
#dfrollingStd.fillna(0)
#print(dfStorage[1][3])
for k,p in dfStorage, dfrollingStd:
    dftemp = pd.DataFrame(dfStorage,columns=[k])
    dfnew=pd.DataFrame(dfrollingStd,columns=[p])
    for i,j in dfStorage, dfrollingStd:
        dftemp = pd.DataFrame(dfStorage,index=[i])
        dfnew=pd.DataFrame(dfrollingStd,index=[j])
        dftemp['-1std'] = pd.DataFrame(dftemp).subtract(dfnew)
        dftemp['+1std'] = pd.DataFrame(dftemp).add(dfnew)
    pd.DataFrame(dftemp).plot()
    plt.ylabel('P/FFO')
```

I expect the output to be 6 separate graphs each with 3 lines. Instead I am not getting anything. My loop is also not executing properly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
We need that code, plus the *entire* error message: include the trace-back.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
excel_file = 'C:/Users/afrydman/Documents/Storage and Data Centers FFO Multiples Data.xlsx'
dfStorage = pd.read_excel(excel_file,sheet_name='Storage Data', index_col='Date')
dfrollingStd = dfStorage.rolling(12).std().shift(-11)
#dfrollingStd.fillna(0)
#print(dfStorage[1][3])
for i in dfStorage:
    dftemp = pd.DataFrame(dfStorage,columns=[i])
    for j in dfrollingStd:
        dfnew=pd.DataFrame(dfrollingStd,columns=[j])
        dftemp['-1std'] = pd.DataFrame(dftemp).subtract(dfnew)
        dftemp['+1std'] = pd.DataFrame(dftemp).add(dfnew)
    pd.DataFrame(dftemp).plot()
    plt.ylabel('P/FFO')
```

This is my updated code and I am still getting the same error. This time it is saying Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1